# Build Time Series Regression Model with categorical and numerical variables using R

Tags: r, time-series, regression

Could anyone explain to me how to build a time series model with regression components and categorical variables?

For example, an AR(1) model with x1,x2,x3 as the regression variables where s=sector, r=rating,t=time

[image]
[image]

So far I tried ARIMA,

```
  sector = as.factor(tbSector)
  rating = as.factor(tbRating)                       
  fit=arima(y,order=c(1,0,0),xreg=as.matrix(sector,rating,x1,x2,x3))
```

but output an error at xreg saying Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A).

Can this problem be resolved via panel regression?

Comment: Maybe the function `tslm` in the package `forecast` can help.

Comment: tslm won't work because Sector and Rating columns are categorical variables. I'm currently searching for solution via panel data regression